# Product of all other numbers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a function which takes an array of numbers as an argument. I want to return a new array with the products of each number except for the number at the current index.

For example, if `arr` had 5 indexes and we were creating the value for index 1, the numbers at index 0, 2, 3 and 4 would be multiplied.

Here is the code I have written:

```
function getProducts(arr) {
let products = [];
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let product = 0;
    for(let value in arr.values()) {
      if(value != arr[i]) {
        product *= value;
      }
    }
    products.push(product);
}
return products;
}
getProducts([1, 7, 3, 4]);
// Output ➞ [0, 0, 0, 0]
// Expected output ➞ [84, 12, 28, 21]
```

As you can see, the desired output does not actualise. I did some experimenting and it appears that the second for loop is never really initiated, as any code I put inside the block does not execute:

```
function getProducts(arr) {
let products = [];
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let product = 0;
    for(let value in arr.values()) {
      console.log('hello!');
      if(value != arr[i]) {
        product *= value;
      }
    }
    products.push(product);
}
return products;
}
getProducts([1, 7, 3, 4]);
// Output ➞ 
// Expected Output ➞ 'hello!'
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your accumilation starts on condition of product = 0, whatever you multiply it by will equal zero, your initial point should be product =1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to change the `in` keyword to `of` keyword. Is not the same a `for..in` than a `for..of`.

`arr.values()` returns an iterator, which has to be iterated with the `of` keyword.

Also, if `product = 0`, then all your multiplications will return 0.

By the way this code is prone to error, because you don't check the current index, but you check if the value that you are multiplying is different than the current value. This will lead to a problem if the same number is duplicated in the array.

And, now talking about good practices, is a bit weird that first you iterate through the array with a `for(var i...` loop and the second time you do it with a `for...in/of`.

I've fixed the code for you:

```
function getProducts(arr) {
    let products = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let product = 1;
        for(let ii = 0; ii < arr.length; ii++) {
            if(i != ii) {
                product *= arr[ii];
            }
        }
        products.push(product);
    }
    return products;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take the product of all numbers and divide by the number of the index to get a product of all except the actual value.

```js
function getProducts(array) {
    var product = array.reduce((a, b) => a * b, 1);
    return array.map(p => product / p);
}

console.log(getProducts([1, 7, 3, 4]));
```

A more reliable approach with an array with one zero. If an array has more than one zero, all products are zero.

The below approach replaces the value at index with one.

```js
function getProducts(array) {
    return array.map((_, i, a) => a.reduce((a, b, j) => a * (i === j || b), 1));
}

console.log(getProducts([1, 7, 0, 4]));
console.log(getProducts([1, 7, 3, 4]));
```

Comment: hopefully one of the entries is not a **0**

Comment: @gkelly, nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do that is get the total product and use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to divide `total` with each value

```js
function getProducts(arr){
  let total = arr.reduce((ac,a) => ac * a,1);
  return arr.map(x => x === 0 ? total : total/x);
}
console.log(getProducts([1, 7, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: this is exactly the same as another solution with exactly the same problem.  x == 0 ? **boom**

Comment: @gkelly Ok I fixed that problem

Answer (score 0):

Explanation: replace the number at **i** with **1** so it doesn't **interfere** with the multiplication.  Also, apply the **fill** on a **copy** of **a** hence the **[...a]**

```js
console.log( [2,3,4,5].map( (n,i,a) => [...a].fill(1,i,i+1).reduce( (a,b) => a*b ) ) )
```